# JpaPagingItemReader failing to read data and move to next step

Tags: java, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa, spring-batch

I have a Spring batch process that reads data from a SQL Server and writes to a file. The query I am using returns 350000 rows and takes about 2 minutes to run on SQL Server studio - so the query is tuned for best performance.

Below is the JobConfiguration class:

```
@Configuration
@Slf4j
public class JobConfiguration {
    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;
    private final StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory;
    private final FileProperties fileProperties;
    private JobProperties jobProperties;
    private FileUtility fileUtility;
    private CompensationDetailStatusRepository compensationDetailStatusRepository;
    private CompensationDetailsRepository compensationDetailsRepository;

    @Autowired
    public JobConfiguration(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, StepBuilderFactory stepBuilderFactory,
                            JobProperties jobProperties, FileProperties fileProperties
    ) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.stepBuilderFactory = stepBuilderFactory;
        this.jobProperties = jobProperties;
        this.fileProperties = fileProperties;
    }

    @Bean
    public Job processExtractJob(ExtractProcessListener listener,
                                        Step processExtract,
                                        Step moveFiles
                                        ) {
        return jobBuilderFactory.get("processExtractJob")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .listener(listener)
                .start(processExtract)
                .on("COMPLETED")
                .to(moveFiles)
                .end()
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step processExtract(ItemReader<Person> PersonReader,
                                      ExtractProcessor extractProcessor,
                                      ExtractWriter extractWriter
    ) {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("processExtract")
                .<Person, ExtractVO>chunk(50)
                .faultTolerant()
                .retryLimit(1)
                .retry(IOException.class)
                .retry(UncheckedIOException.class)
                .reader(PersonReader)
                .processor(extractProcessor)
                .writer(extractWriter)
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExtractWriter extractWriter() {
        return new ExtractWriter();
    }

    @Bean
    public ExtractProcessor extractProcessor() {
        return new ExtractProcessor();
    }

    @Bean
    public Step moveFiles() {
        return stepBuilderFactory.get("moveFiles")
                .tasklet((contribution, chunkContext) -> {
                    fileUtility.moveFiles(String.format("%s*", fileProperties.getFileNamePrefix()),
                            fileProperties.getFileStagingPath(), fileProperties.getFileTargetPath());
                    return RepeatStatus.FINISHED;
                }).build();
    }

    @Bean
    @StepScope
    public ItemReader<Person> PersonReader(EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory) {
        String query = "Select new com.example.Person (DTL.personId,DTL.description) FROM DETAIL DTL;";
        JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();
        reader.setQueryString(query);
        reader.setTransacted(false);
        reader.setPageSize(jobProperties.getReaderPageSize());
        reader.setEntityManagerFactory(entityManagerFactory);
        reader.setPageSize(jobProperties.getReaderPageSize());
        return reader;
    }

    @Bean
    public ExtractProcessListener jobExecutionListener() {
        return new ExtractProcessListener();
    }
}
```

Below is the java object (Person.java) for the database resultset:

```
@ToString
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
public class PersonCompensation {
    private String personId;
    private String description;
}
```

When I run the batch process, I get the following exception:

```
2020-04-15 21:34:59.172 ERROR 11748 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step processExtract in job processExtractJob
org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:196) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108) ~[spring-batch-infrastructure-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.item.support...
    ... 27 common frames omitted
2020-04-15 21:34:59.946  WARN 11748 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.b.f.support.DisposableBeanAdapter    : Invocation of destroy method 'close' failed on bean with name 'scopedTarget.personCompensationReader': org.springframework.batch.item.ItemStreamException: Error while closing item reader
2020-04-15 21:35:00.277 ERROR 11748 --- [rTaskExecutor-1] o.s.batch.core.job.AbstractJob           : Encountered fatal error executing job
org.springframework.batch.core.JobExecutionException: Flow execution ended unexpectedly
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowJob.doExecute(FlowJob.java:140) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:306) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core...
Caused by: org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.FlowExecutionException: Next state not found in flow=processExtractJob for state=processExtractJob.processExtract with exit status=FAILED
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.flow.support.SimpleFlow.nextState(SimpleFlow.java:230) ~[spring-batch-core-3.0.8.RELEASE.jar:3.0.8.RELEASE]
    at org.springframework.batch.core...
Exit Code: FAILED
Exit Desc: org.springframework.batch.core.step.skip.NonSkippableReadException: Non-skippable exception during read
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.FaultTolerantChunkProvider.read(FaultTolerantChunkProvider.java:105)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.item.SimpleChunkProvider$1.doInIteration(SimpleChunkProvider.java:116)
    at org.springframework.batch...
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.JpaPagingItemReader.doReadPage(JpaPagingItemReader.java:196)
    at org.springframework.batch.item.database.AbstractPagingItemReader.doRead(AbstractPagingItemReader.java:108)
    at org.springframework.batch.item...
    ... 27 more
```

I have three questions:

1. Does the spring batch process query and fetch all the 350000 rows at once and give the records to processor in chunks of 50 (chunk size) ?
2. I have this line in the code `JpaPagingItemReader<Person> reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();`. Should the Person class be a Entity object for this to work or any will a POJO work fine?
3. What could be causing the above exception?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> 1. Does the spring batch process query and fetch all the 350000 rows at once and give the records to processor in chunks of 50 (chunk size) ?

No, it will read only `pageSize` items at once, not all of them (that's the point of a paging reader). ChunkSize and PageSize are different parameters. For example, you can read a page of 100 items and have 10 chunks of 10 items for each page. Matching the pageSize and chunkSize usually gives better performance. Please refer to the [Javadoc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/docs/4.2.x/api/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.html).

> 2. I have this line in the code JpaPagingItemReader reader = new JpaPagingItemReader<>();. Should the Person class be a Entity object for this to work or any will a POJO work fine?

Yes, otherwise I don't see the purpose of using a JPA reader (a JDBC one would be enough).

> 3. What could be causing the above exception?

You have a NullPointerException [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-batch/blob/3.0.x/spring-batch-infrastructure/src/main/java/org/springframework/batch/item/database/JpaPagingItemReader.java#L196) which means the entity manager is `null`. You need to call `afterPropertiesSet` on your reader to make sure it is correctly configured.

Comment: Setting afterPropertiesSet did not help. I switched to JdbcPagingItemReader and it solved the purpose.